# migration from .net to oracle 11g

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, 3des

I need to migrate the following 3des encription process from .net to oracle 11g

```
    using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    private const string strKey = "H9p-S5m2Dh6Fe7Ls3-Qs1D2e4Z";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var strToEncrypt = "test";
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
        byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strKey));
        Console.WriteLine("v_key net = "+BitConverter.ToString(byteHash).Replace("-",""));
        objHashMD5 = null;
        objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
        objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; //CBC, CFB
        objDESCrypto.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        Console.WriteLine("iv net = "+BitConverter.ToString(stringToHex("0123456789ABCDEF")).Replace("-",""));
        objDESCrypto.IV = stringToHex("0123456789ABCDEF");
        byteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("src net = "+BitConverter.ToString(byteBuff).Replace("-",""));
        var hashbyte = objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("encrypted_str net = "+BitConverter.ToString(hashbyte).Replace("-",""));
        
        Console.WriteLine("encrypted_str64 net = " + Convert.ToBase64String(objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().
                    TransformFinalBlock(hashbyte, 0, hashbyte.Length)));
        var decrypted_str = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString
                (objDESCrypto.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock
                (hashbyte, 0, hashbyte.Length));
        Console.WriteLine("decrypted_str net = "+decrypted_str);
        string hexString = "43480170";
        
    }
    
    public static byte[] stringToHex(string hexString){
        //uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        //byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
        //return floatVals;
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hexString.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
    }
}
```

available in https://dotnetfiddle.net/hGZZts
whose output is

```
v_key net = 8B928C8346648BDDB14B627EFF4E66F1
iv net = 0123456789ABCDEF
src net = 74657374
encrypted_str net = F7BC988C0EA6EEE5
encrypted_str64 net = 73A6DqCayTc=
decrypted_str net = test
```

The oracle procedure i wrote is

```
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY Criptografia AS
    -- Clave de encriptación (asegúrate de que sea igual a la clave en C#)
    strKeyDataAD CONSTANT VARCHAR2(26) := 'H9p-S5m2Dh6Fe7Ls3-Qs1D2e4Z';
    
    PROCEDURE EncryptDataAD(strToEncrypt IN VARCHAR2) AS
        l_mod_ecb pls_integer;
        v_key raw(32);
        encrypted_str VARCHAR2(4000);
        encryptedBase64_str VARCHAR2(4000);
        decrypted_str VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
        l_mod_ecb := dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES+ dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_ZERO ;
         dbms_output.put_line('l_mod_ecb oracle: '|| l_mod_ecb);
        v_key := dbms_crypto.hash(
            utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strKeyDataAD, 'AL32UTF8'),
            dbms_crypto.hash_md5
          );
        dbms_output.put_line('v_key oracle: '|| (v_key));
        --dbms_output.put_line('DEFAULT_IV oracle: '|| (dbms_crypto.LEGACY_DEFAULT_IV));--DBMS_CRYPTO.LEGACY_DEFAULT_IV
        dbms_output.put_line('src oracle: '|| utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'));
        encrypted_str := dbms_crypto.encrypt(
                                  src => utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strToEncrypt, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                  typ => dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_ZERO,
                                  --typ => dbms_crypto.DES3_CBC_PKCS5,
                                  key => dbms_crypto.hash(
                                        utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strKeyDataAD, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                        dbms_crypto.hash_md5
                                      )
                                  ,iv => hextoraw('0123456789ABCDEF')
                                  );
        dbms_output.put_line('encrypted_str oracle: '|| encrypted_str);
       
        dbms_output.put_line('encryptedBase64_str oracle: '|| utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(encrypted_str)));
        decrypted_str := dbms_crypto.decrypt(
                                  src => encrypted_str,
                                  typ => dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_3DES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_ZERO,
                                  --typ => dbms_crypto.DES3_CBC_PKCS5,
                                  key => dbms_crypto.hash(
                                        utl_i18n.string_to_raw(strKeyDataAD, 'AL32UTF8'),
                                        dbms_crypto.hash_md5
                                      )
                                  ,iv => hextoraw ( '0123456789ABCDEF' )
                                  );
        
        dbms_output.put_line('decrypted_str oracle: '|| UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(decrypted_str,'AL32UTF8'));

        --RETURN encrypted_str;
    END EncryptDataAD;
END Criptografia;
```

whose output is

```
l_mod_ecb oracle: 12545
v_key oracle: 8B928C8346648BDDB14B627EFF4E66F1
src oracle: 74657374
encrypted_str oracle: 28F7DA0F3B338BB1
encryptedBase64_str oracle: KPfaDzszi7E=
decrypted_str oracle: test
```

As you can see v_key (md5 hash in bytes) and src (input in bytes) are the same, but the output is different.
i'tried changing the padding in oracle procedure (PAD_PKCS5, PAD_NONE and PAD_ZERO) and the chaining modifier (CHAIN_ECB,CHAIN_CBC,CHAIN_CFB y CHAIN_OFB) but i wasn't able to return the same result than my .net aplication.
English isn't my native language so i apologize for any grammar error
thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the encrypted string being *decrypted*?

Comment: @pmdba it is not doing it right now, i'm comparing byte to byte

Comment: My point is that the algorithms may not produce the same byte-level hash, for a variety of reasons. Unless you're doing encryption in one and decryption in the other, *it doesn't matter*. As long as you can encrypt/decrypt in PL/SQL, it doesn't matter if the encrypted hash for c# looks the same or not.

Comment: oh, i understand. In this case i have to encode in pl/sql and decode in c#/Net.

Comment: There are random number generators involved in the encryption algorithms that make getting the same hash text very, very improbable. What is your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LeandroLocani 3DES is broken for almost 2 decades. Both .NET and Oracle have far, far better encryption already. What's the point of this code? All it does is *expose* the data worse than if it was unencrypted

Comment: If you want to protect data on the network, you can configure TLS encryption on the database connection itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are absolutely right, but in this case the algoritm is required. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Required by whom? Requiring what exactly? Do you have that in writing? Otherwise *you* may end up in a malpractice trial. 3DES is *widely known* to be not just insecure but trivial to break for over 20 years.. You can't claim ignorance

Comment: If anything, using 3DES violates NIST guidance that requires its complete removal by 2024 and definitely violates PCI-DSS requirements. PCI actually requires TLS 1.2 and up

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem is that in both cases I am putting a 128-bit key but 3des requires a 192-bit key and .net to complete it repeating the first 8 bytes and Oracle does it in some other way.
So the solution was to repeat the first 8 bytes in the oracle key so the result of 3des was the same in both sides

Comment: The problem is that you even try to use 3DES. [This CVE, combined with the inadequate key size of DES and 3DES, led to NIST deprecating DES and 3DES for new applications in 2017, and for all applications by the end of 2023. It has been replaced with the more secure, more robust AES.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES)